# Developing an Eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

It's my first time to develop an RCP application with Eclipse 3.8.
My question may seem weird but it is really confusing for me. Where can I put the code for my application? If I create the needed classes for my app where can I use their objects? In the `Application.java` class? I'm confused, and Internet tutorials focus only on the visual aspect and SWT, not on how to code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An eclipse RCP application is basically an eclipse plugin.

I suggest starting off with an RCP application based on a simple template (e.g., the Hello World template). To create such an application, create a new plug-in project (*New > Other > Plug-in Project*), set the target platform to Eclipse 3.8, let the Wizard generate an Activator, tick the checkboxes "This plug-in will make contributions to the UI" and "Would you like to create a rich client application: Yes", and choose any of the available templates on the next wizard page.

Have a good look at the generated classes. You're right in assuming that basically `Application.java` is the starting point of your application. However, note that an Eclipse plug-in is an OSGi(-compliant) bundle, so there's also the plug-in/bundle activator. Something to also keep in mind is that one of the general configuration points is the `plugin.xml` and its extensions tab.

I suggest that you have a good look at some of the tutorials available (there are a few which help you get started without just focusing on the graphics level, although it is important that you get yourself accustomed to, e.g., the SWT and JFace APIs). I personally gained *a lot* from reading McAffer et al.s [Eclipse RCP book](http://eclipsercp.org/).

There is a [blog post which lists a number of options to get started with the Eclipse RCP](http://blog.sdruskat.net/getting-started-with-the-eclipse-rcp/). (Disclaimer: Shameless self-promotion)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

what i've realized is, the generated classes in a RCP project folder are only to manage the lifecycle and appearance  of the RCP application, that's it.

### For everything else we want our application to do, we need to write seperate classes.

For eg, if you created a view (class that implements IViewPart interface) then u need to add that view to the RCP application using `plugin.xml` file.

following is a short description of these classes (what basically they do)

- `Application.java` - starting point of application, similar to main(-) method.
- `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java` - for window size, title, menubar, toolbar, status bar configuration and visibility.
- `WorkbenchAdvisor.java` - identifies the initial perspective and which WorkbenchWindowAdvisor to use.
- `Perspective.java` - arrangement of views and editors (like we have in Java Perspective, Debug Perspective in Eclipse IDE)
- `ActionBarAdvisor.java` - for creating actions but the use of commands framework is encouraged  (*see page no.292 of Eclipse Rich Client Platform, Second Edition- by Jeff McAffer* [http://www.amazon.com/Eclipse-Rich-Client-Platform-Edition/dp/0321603788](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321603788) )

Comment: There is a good tutorial at this website for Basic RCP. Hope it helps you. http://javacodingtutorial.blogspot.de/2015/08/creating-simple-hello-world-rcp.html